# Fs2 handling errors between pipes?

Tags: scala, fs2

I am trying to write a program that grabs files, makes changes, then saves them elsewhere.

So my program looks something like this:

```scala
def processFiles: Stream[F, Unit] =
  getFilePaths.flatMap(path =>
    downloadFile(path)
      .through(scanForViruses)
      .through(encrypt)
      .through(saveElsewhere)
  )

def downloadFile(path: Path): Stream[F, Byte]

def scanForViruses: Pipe[F, Byte, Byte]

def encrypt: Pipe[F, Byte, Byte]

def saveElsewhere: Pipe[F, Byte, Unit]
```

Some of these steps can fail, and with the code above a single failed file stops other files from processing. So I need to add some handling:

```scala
getFilePaths.flatMap(path =>
    downloadFile(path)
      .handleErrorsWith(e => log.error("failed at download", e) >> Stream.empty)
      .through(scanForViruses)
      .handleErrorsWith(e => log.error("failed at scan", e) >> Stream.empty)      
      .through(encrypt)
      .handleErrorsWith(e => log.error("failed at encrypt", e) >> Stream.empty)   
      .through(saveElsewhere)
      .handleErrorsWith(e => log.error("failed at save", e) >> Stream.empty)
  )
```

This catches the errors correctly, but all of the elements in the stream before the exception are still passed through

for example, if the first file stream looks like this: Stream(Byte1, Byte2, Exception) then handleErrorWith will return Stream(Byte1, Byte2) which wont make sense for a file.

On the other hand, if I `rethrow` the exception (or leave it alone), I get the overall behavior I want: It fails the stream for that particular file. But every error handler will be called on the exception and I have no information on where it actually failed:

```scala
getFilePaths.flatMap(path =>
    downloadFile(path).attempt.evalMap(handler1).rethrow
      .through(scanForViruses).attempt.evalMap(handler2).rethrow      
      .through(encrypt).attempt.evalMap(handler3).rethrow      
      .through(saveElsewhere).attempt.evalMap(handler4)
  )
```

^^ the above will call all handlers on an exception if it happens in `downloadFile`

is there a way to fail the entire stream on the first exception, and keep track of where it failed, without having to compile the stream every time I do a step?

Comment: Since it is stream processing, by the time `n`th element fails at step 1, the `x`th step will have processed `n - x`th element. This is exactly what streams are supposed to do. What you require will need you to not use stream processing.

Comment: Although attempt kind of does that for you, but then are you actually running a Stream ? Or, is it a batch disguised as a Stream ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems my use case is not an intended purpose for streams.

In other words, the structure of my original program was off.

I am writing in tagless final and the functions I was using as eliminators were written as `Pipe[F, Byte, Unit]`, but the functionality I want will require something closer to `Stream[F, Byte] => F[Unit]`, and then I will just use the built in error handling in `F`